# How to Change backcolor of dynamically created button from another form

Tags: c#

I have created a windows form application, where it adds some button when the form1 is loaded. I want to change the color of the form1 button when the form2 button is clicked

```
 Point newLoc = new Point(20, 35);
        int ButtonHeight = 0;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Button b = new Button
                {
                    Name = "Btn" + i.ToString(),
                    Size = new Size(120, 60),
                    Location = newLoc, Text = i.ToString(),
                    BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen
                };

                i++;
                if ((i % 10) == 0)
                {
                    ButtonHeight = ButtonHeight + b.Height + 10;
                    newLoc = new Point(-110, 25 + ButtonHeight);
                }
                newLoc.Offset(b.Width + 10, 0);
                Controls.Add(b);
            }
        }

        public void Changecolor(Button b)
        {
           b.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }

//form2

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = new Button
            {
                Name = "Btn" + textBox1.Text
            };
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Change_color(b);
        }
```

if i type a number in form2.textbox and click form2.button. it should change the backcolor of form1.button with the name "Btn" + textBox1.Text

Answer (score 0):

```
button.BackColor = Color.Red
```

where ever you want it to happen

Comment: I think OP needs to know how to reference the buttons, not how to set a property.

Comment: @Crowcoder right, please check my answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

When you call other function with new keyword, normally you cannot change their property.
You need to declare one object for opener form and set it's component like below (please change names for yours, it's going to be working for you):

```
 //In form 2:
 var frmName= (frmName)Application.OpenForms["frmName"];

 frmName.Button1.BackColor=Color.Red
```

Edit:  Yes you can access button which created dynamically but need to change access modifier to public.

```
    // In form1: 
     public Button b =new Button();

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        b.Name = "btn";
        b.Size = new Size(120, 60);
        b.Text = "denemee";
        b.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen;

        Controls.Add(b);
```

}

Comment: I want to change the color of the button created dynamically

Comment: check my edit @eanasthaichi it would be solve your problem

Comment: this code will create one button, and it will change the color of that button. I have used for loop to create button and want to change the color of that button which

Comment: So? modify this code to yours, create list or something and store your buttons and numarate button in it and change color which are you want.

Comment: List<Button> btnList= new List<Button>(); and add your buttons to list and call list from form 2, or pass your list a parameter